# parameter complex object is coming into JavaScript function as undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

On Page 1 I get the object I need:

```
ProjectSearchCriteria = (GBLProjectSearchCriteria)Session[GblConstants.SESSION_PROJECT_SEARCH_CRITERIA];
```

I'm trying to pass this to an API on a page load of Page 2.

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="../x.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmProjectSearchResults" runat="server">
        </form>
        <script src="../Scripts/ProjectsTreeView.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CreateProjectTree(<%= ProjectSearchCriteria %>);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript function:

```
function CreateProjectTree(searchCriteria)
{
    debugger;
    var projects = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../api/projects?searchcriteria =" + searchCriteria,
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "seasons"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: projects,
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataUrlField: "LinksTo",
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataTextField: ["Title"],
        select: treeviewSelect
    });

    function treeviewSelect(e) {
        var node = this.dataItem(e.node);
        window.open(node.NotificationLink, "_self");
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your browser throwing any javascript error? Why is this not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CreateProjectTree("\"" + <%= ProjectSearchCriteria %> + "\"");
</script>
```

Comment: +1 - this is almost as good advice as it can get for the question, maybe some JSON-ification of ProjectSearchCriteria would be nice, but not possible in generic case based on information provided. @Rj - *you* need to look at resulting HTML and see what is actually generated and if it matches you expectations.

Comment: after I added what Alesandro said, now I get ""NaN" as the value of the object (in the java script function)

Comment: what is the value of "ProjectSearchCriteria"?